# not able to configure HTTP analysis service

Tags: ssas

I want to connect to cube using HTTP/ internet outside.
I already set up :

- copy Folder OLAP in inetpub/wwwroot
- Added Aplication pool in IIS
- Added website with application pool i just created
- enable anonymous    in user account
- Added script map dll in handler mapping

But I Still cannot connect to database.
the message is "either a connection cannot be made to the server or analysis services is not running on the computer specified"

Help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting over and running this PowerShell script:
http://blog.gbrueckl.at/2014/10/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-using-powershell-2/

Comment: I am trying using that script but still cannot connect. the message problem is still the same

Comment: I can connect via SSMS. http://localhost:8080/olap/msmdpump.dll.
buat i can't connect via excel with different PC using internet.
My firewall off